# How To encrypt SQLite database in ionic

Tags: sqlite, encryption, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am programming the hybrid application using ionic. To store the data on the device i am using sqlite plugin of ngcordova. Can somebody give me advice, how to encrypt the database file of sqlite ?

thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlcipher-adapter for secure your file in the device.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.